# Event Sourcing: How to model relationship between different events?

Tags: event-sourcing

I am new to Event Sourcing and I have encountered an example which I am not quite sure the pros and cons of different approaches.

Let's say this is a bank example, I have three entities Account, Deposit and Transfer.

My idea is, when a use deposits, command `bank.deposit` will create two events:
`deposit.created` and `account.deposited`. Can I or should I include the `deposit.created` event `uuid` in `account.deposited` as a reference?

Taking to the next step, if later the bank has a transfer feature, should I made a separate event `account.transfer_received` or I should created a more general event `account.credited` to be used by both deposit and transfer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A good article to review is [Nobody Needs Reliable Messaging](https://www.infoq.com/articles/no-reliable-messaging).  One key observation is that you often need identifiers at the domain level.

For instance, when I look at my bank account, and see that the account history includes a specific deposit, there is an identifier *for the deposit* that is reported in the view.

If you imagine it from an event sourced perspective, before the deposit the balance was X, and the history did not include deposit 12345; after processing the deposit, the balance was X+Y *and deposit 12345 was in the account history*.

(This means, among other things, that if a *second* copy of deposit 12345 were to appear, the domain model would know to ignore it even if the identifier for the *event* were different).

Now, there are reasons that you might want to keep various message ids around.  See Hohpe's work on Enterprise Integration Patterns; in particular [Correlation Identifier](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CorrelationIdentifier.html).

> should I made a separate event

Usually.  "Make the implicit, explicit".  The fact that two events happen to have similar representations is not a reason to blur them when the ubiquitous  language distinguishes the two.

It's somewhat analogous, in motivation, to providing a [task based ui](https://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/task-based-ui/) or eschewing the user of [generic repositories](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository/).